# My visual studio code won't open a new folder

Tags: visual-studio-code, directory

I installed the Visual Studio code for the first time yesterday, but when I open a folder in Navigation, the folder won't continue to open. I'm using the later version of iMac 2013(it's the Catalina version) and visual studio code version is 1.78.2. Visual Studio code was reinstalled, but the same thing is repeated because it was not fully initialized, and attempts to initialize through iMac's terminal failed.

1. I want a solution to the new folder not opening at all.
2. (If it doesn't work #1) Please tell me how to fully initialize and reinstall Visual Studio.
   (I hope you don't reset as much as possible. IMac terminal initialization failed)

Comment: what do you mean by "open a folder in navigation"? screenshots might actually help here to show what exactly you're doing. please also try to provide an elaborated description in words. we can't really help if we don't understand the problem.